# Merging two dataframes into one on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate dataframes and i would like to merge them based on a specific column. I have tried to concat the two but it just places the dataframes on top of each other. and i have tried pd.merge but it duplicates the other columns

Here is what i have...

[image: Current Dataframe]

I want something similar to this where the dates are merged and the symbols share the date.
[image]

Here is some dummy code if you'd like to implement an example

```
df_msft = [['2020-1-1', 10], ['2020-1-2', 15], ['2020-1-3', 14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_msft , columns = ['datetime', 'price'])

df_aapl = [['2020-1-1', 10], ['2020-1-2', 15], ['2020-1-3', 14]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_aapl , columns = ['datetime', 'price'])
```

Comment: One thing to be careful about here is the difference between the data in a dataframe and how that data is displayed to a user. You can easily create a dataframe which repeats the date in each line and then display that in a table format like you show in the screenshot.

Comment: What do you mean by "it duplicates the other columns" when you tried pd.merge? Which "other" columns are duplicated?

Comment: Lets say i merged it based on the 'datetime'  column, after merging it would duplicate the columns with the same name which are all of them such as: Ticker_x, Ticker_y

Comment: I think I get what you mean. So if both dataframes have a column named `high`, then the "merged" data frame will have two columns, one from each of the original dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat`:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['MSFT', 'AAPL']).droplevel(1) \
        .rename_axis('symbol').set_index('datetime', append=True) \
        .swaplevel().sort_index()
print(out)

# Output
                 price
datetime symbol       
2020-1-1 AAPL       10
         MSFT       10
2020-1-2 AAPL       15
         MSFT       15
2020-1-3 AAPL       14
         MSFT       14
```

Export to excel:

```
out.to_excel('output.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check my last update? I forgot `sort_index`